# Standard Error of the ratio of Binomial variates

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, standard-error, ratio

What's the right way to compute the Standard Error of the Mean of the ratio of two random variables that follow a binomial distribution?

I asked a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153733/standard-error-of-ratio-of-weibull-variates) using Weibull distributions and now I'm interested on the relationship between binomial distributions.

I'm running an experiment that tracks success/failure rate of two distinct groups over 7 days in a row. These two two groups follow a binomial distribution:

$$X \sim \mbox{B}({ n }_{ 1 },{ p }_{ 1 })$$
$$Y \sim \mbox{B}({ n }_{ 2 },{ p }_{ 2 })$$

The experiment starts with a sample of ~ 10k observations in each group but the sample size differs during the following days (eg: I can have `[10k 5k 7k 3k 2k 1k 0.5k 0.8k]` observations for a group. **Each number equals the number of observations of that group in a specific day, no day will have more than the initial sample size observations, an observation on day 3 can also be observed on day 5 and all observations will always be included on day 0**).

I want to calculate the $SEM$ of the following ratio:

$$Z=\frac {X-Y}{Y}$$

The method I'm following is obtaining the **Expected Value** and **Variation** of the ratio by using [Taylor Expansions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables).

Since both distributions have $N*\hat{p} > 5$ and $N*(1-\hat{p})> 5$ we can assume it follows a normal distribution and compute the $SEM$ by using:

$${SEM_i}= \frac{{\sigma_i}}{\sqrt{N_i}}$$

where ${N_i}$ is the sample size in day $i$.

It turns out that this yields

- a very small $SEM$ (about 0.2~1% of the mean) when I use ${N_i}={Nx_i}+{Ny_i}$ and
- a really huge $SEM$ (about 2~3 times the mean) when I use ${N_i} = 7-i$ (the number of days I run the experiment), so it makes me question the right $N$ to use.

Which one of these points is the correct one to get the $ {N_i} $?

Comment: $Y$ has a positive probability of being $0$ (so too does $X$) which is going to cause issues with $\frac {X-Y}{Y}$

Comment: Yea, but that probability is way too small, that will rarely occur - if not never.

Comment: Even if the probability is $1/(10^{10^{100}})$, the population variance of the ratio will not be finite. You'd have to explicitly exclude zero (making it truncated binomial) to get something it makes sense to try to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it's a really good point to consider and clarifies the question a lot. Just to get a little bit back to the point (that I'm still struggling a bit) of the sample size ${N_i}$: for simplicity, suppose that I change my $Z$ to $Z=X-Y$. In that case (now excluding the issues with division by 0), which ${N_i}$ should I use to obtain the $SEM$ of $Z$? (here I'm more trying to understand the theory behind choosing the right ${N_i}$)

Comment: What is the applied problem which leads you to consider the ratio of binomials?  Knowing that, maybe we can propose something better.